# Order by CASE ASC

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, case

First time using CASE in PDO (mySQL database)

I'm trying to ORDER BY a date, but only if the date is not 0000-00-00 (it can be)

But it seems to ignore the case all together.. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE groupid = '.$groupid.' ORDER BY CASE WHEN groupdate != "0000-00-00" THEN groupdate END ASC';

$STH = $conn->query($sql);

if ($STH->rowCount() > 0) {

    while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {

        // output the rows

    }

} else {

    echo '<p>No dates found!</p>';

}
```

Comment: Stick with the MySQL part. Let's get that bit working first.

Comment: How do you mean? Database is MySQL

Comment: When you ask an SQL question, it is better to post SQL statement only, without any application code.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to avoid any "show some more of your code!" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do with zero-date rows?
Return them after other rows?
Then use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE groupid = $groupid 
ORDER BY groupdate = '0000-00-00', groupdate
```

groupdate = '0000-00-00' is a boolean expresion and returns 1 for matching rows, 0 for non-matching rows. 0 comes before 1 in ascending order.
Non-zero rows are sorted by groupdate.

Comment: Hi, looks good and simple, will try it now. The important thing is that any dates that are not 0000-00-00 will come out first

Comment: It works. But now that I see it, I'm reconsidering if those dates should come out first anyway (it messes up the overall date overview).. have to think more ;) But thx

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [CASE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) you should have an `ELSE` statement in the end. Try something like:

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE groupid = '.$groupid.' ORDER BY (CASE WHEN groupdate != "0000-00-00" THEN groupdate ELSE groupid END)';`